# Are Costco-refilled print cartridges generally unreliable?

Tags: printer

I recently had my print cartridges refilled at Costo for my HP 2510 all-in-one printer.  They worked for a few days, but now I've got a constant "Remove and check print cartridges" message on the printer with all the buttons flashing and I can't use or reset the printer.  Am I overlooking some way to make the printer recheck the cartridges, or am I just screwed until I shell out for brand new cartridges?  Has anyone had good luck getting their cartridges refilled at Costco, or are refilled cartridges generally bad news?

Comment: The last time I tried to do the money-saving technique of using off-brand ink, the ink cartridge came with a little hand-crankable drill to create a hole in the cartridge.  I do remember the result of ink being all over the table.  I do remember the result of the cartridge not working.  I do remember deciding not to try such nonsense again.  (Still, I fully agree with the first 32 words of ChrisF's "NOTE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the refill is of high quality compatible ink then you run the risk of this sort of error.

Actually because the cartridges are designed for single use even if you refilled with ink of equal quality to the original you still might get failures.

NOTE: I'm not saying that the current situation where printer manufacturers charge an arm and a leg for replacement cartridges is a good place to be. Ink cartridges should be easily refillable and the manufactures and stores should have a system in place whereby you can return the empties and get a discount off new ones. The old cartridges would then be returned to the manufacturer and either refilled correctly or recycled safely.

Comment: So what is it that my 2510 is sensing about the refilled cartridge that causes it to complain?

Comment: Anything I suggest would only be speculation. It could be that the ink is slightly the wrong colour or consistency or that the act of refilling has broken the sensing circuit. Have you tried talking to Costo to see if it was just a refill that went bad?

Answer (score 0):

I've had excellent results using Costco refilled ink cartridges for my Canon MX 882 AIO printer.  The printer does constantly display "low ink" messages which I simply ignore (as advised by almost any cartridge refill company).  I just wait until the print quality diminishes and then get the cartridge refilled.  The cost is less than 1/2 of OEM cartridges and I do not detect a difference in quality.  The ONLY disadvantage is the annoying dialog box saying low ink......which is hard to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried Costco refills and they were leaking when I got home. I wiped them off, put them in (two of them) -- one of them is generating an error message telling me to replace that cartridge! I have no idea if the other cartridge is ok or not because I can't print with the magenta ink error message. GRRRRRR!

Comment: Take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your answer

Answer (score -1):

I have a Canon Pixma three-in-one printer and the Costco refills lasted about a week each.  The message from the printer is that they are out of ink, but they are clearly not.  I have an empty caertridge and they are heavier and sound full.  The refills at Costco were a waste of money.